# Regex - sequence of the same character

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a sequence of three same letters and i need an expression not greedy that find them and stop  at the first occurrence.

example:

aaa  => `true`

aaahhh => `false`

I tried using `([a-zA-Z])\1\1`  but this will match any three sequenced letters.

The expression that i need should be like this:
x(expression)

x match => aaa  - `true`

xx match => aaajjj -`true`

xxx match => aaajjjhhh -`true`

xx => aaakooo - `false`

Comment: If xx and xxx it the number of occurrences, you could use a quantifier `^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}$` https://regex101.com/r/OLNsBJ/1

Comment: x is the (expression)

Comment: Looks like `x` stands for three consecutive letters. A `xx` stands for two times three consecutive letters and `xxx` stands for three times three consecutive letters. Therefor `xx` does not match `aaakooo` since a single letter is breaking the pattern. Correct? If so, I think @Thefourthbird got what you want where `{2}` is the "pattern" aka the amount of x's.

Comment: There is a contradiction between test cases: why is `aaahhh` false and `aaajjj` true?

Comment: Each expression should  match only three letters (expression=aaa. --Expression+expression =aaajjj

Comment: Please check comment by @Thefourthbird, I believe that's what you need.

Comment: Why is `aaahhh => false`? Thefourthbird's suggestion [matches it](https://regex101.com/r/rakJev/1). Actually, `^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1)+$` would match all correctly but this one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I believe the top two samples are meant only for `^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){1}$` if I interpret the question correctly. The OP then goes further in adding additional x's. An `x` seem to stand for "expression". So a double x are two expressions. However, only OP can confirm =)

Comment: @JvdV yes you are right  the x stands for expression of only three letters

Answer (score 2):

If x is the number of occurrences of 3 times the same character, you could use a quantifier `{x}`

```
^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLNsBJ/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `([a-zA-Z])\1\1`
- `){2}` Close group and repeat x times (In this case 2)
- `$` End of string

```js
console.log(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1)$/.test("aaa"));
console.log(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1)$/.test("aaahhh"));
console.log(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}$/.test("aaajjj"));
console.log(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){3}$/.test("aaajjjhhh"));
console.log(/^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}$/.test("aaakooo"));
```

Comment: this work but lets say you have something like this

```^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}[1-9]```

```aaabbb9ccchhh```
this will only match up to the number  how will you match the rest of the sequenced letters

Comment: @kag11 If you also want to match that, you can omit the anchors `(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}` https://regex101.com/r/CBCVMZ/1 Or you can extend it optionally repeating the digit and the same pattern using capturing group 2 `^(?:([a-zA-Z])\1\1){2}(?:[1-9](?:([a-zA-Z])\2\2){2})*$` https://regex101.com/r/9qy2XM/1